# Passing custom functions into a base abstract class for delayed execution

Tags: c++, design-patterns, c++17, std, std-function

I'd like to learn how to have an abstraction over a Task class that can take any function or functor objects (along with its arguments etc) and store it for later execution or distribute it on some threads, whatever.

I have experimented a bit with `std::function` and template classes, but haven't succeeded. So I'd like to first make it compiled and then run to get familiar with the concepts, then I will search for some more efficient pattern for my needs. So, the question is that how I can get my code compiled firstly for the first step? The code has shown below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

class ITask
{
    public:
    virtual ~ITask() = default;
    virtual void execute() = 0;
};

template<typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
class GameTask : ITask
{
    explicit GameTask(std::function<ReturnType(Args...)>& func) :
        func_(func)
    {}

    void execute()
    {
        // func(Args...); ??
    }

private:
    std::function<ReturnType(Args...)> func_;
};


// lets imitate some bigger classes with various methods
class BigClassA
{
public:
    void func1(int a) { std::cout << ++a; }
    int func2(const std::string& s) { std::cout << s; return b; }

    int b = 4;
};

class BigClassB
{
public:
    double func1(BigClassA& bca, int i) { bca.b += i; return 0.1; }
};

int main()
{
    BigClassA a;
    BigClassB b;

    // perform immidiately by current main thread:
    a.func1(2);
    b.func1(a, 3);
    a.func2("Hello");


    //store under queue for later execution
    std::queue<std::unique_ptr<ITask>> queue;

    /*  a.func1(2);  */
    // queue.push(std::make_unique<GameTask>( [&a](){ a.func1(2); } ));

    /*  b.func1(a, 3);  */
    //  queue.push(std::make_unique<GameTask>(  ));

    /*  a.func2("Hello");  */
    // queue.push(std::make_unique<GameTask>(  ));


    while (queue.size())
    {
        queue.front()->execute();
        queue.pop();
    }

}
```

edit:

Varadic was indeed needles here. Thats the code I currently end up with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

class ITask
{
public:
    virtual ~ITask() = default;
    virtual void execute() = 0;
};

class GameTask : public ITask
{
public:
    GameTask(std::function<void()> func) : func_(func) {}

    void execute() final
    {
        func_();
    }

private:
    std::function<void()> func_;
};

// lets imitate some bigger classes with various methods
class BigClassA
{
public:
    void func1(int a) const { std::cout << ++a; }
    int func2(const std::string& s) { std::cout << s; return b; }

    int b = 4;
};

class BigClassB
{
public:
    double func1(BigClassA& bca, int i) { bca.b += i; return 0.1; }
};

int main()
{
    BigClassA a;
    BigClassB b;

    // perform immidiately by current main thread:
    a.func1(2);
    b.func1(a, 3);
    a.func2("Hello");

    //store under queue for later execution
    std::queue<std::unique_ptr<ITask>> queue;

    queue.push(std::make_unique<GameTask>( [&a]() { a.func1(2); } ));

    queue.push(std::make_unique<GameTask>( [&a, &b]() {b.func1(a, 3); } ));

    queue.push(std::make_unique<GameTask>( [&a]() { a.func2("Hello"); } ));


    // delayed execution
    while (queue.size())
    {
        queue.front()->execute();
        queue.pop();
    }

}
```

I'd like to hear about every improvement I can add.

Comment: Wait, so you haven't succeeded with `std::function` because it's not efficient? How did you benchmark this? What are your requirements?

Comment: Or, you didn't succeed with `std::function` because you couldn't get it to work? If so, how did it fail, what was the problem?

Comment: tl;dr you seem to be conflating functionality with efficiency, but they're two different questions and you haven't given enough information to answer either.

Comment: Your `GameTask::execute` method is of type `void()`. What is the point of storing `std::function<ReturnType(Args...)>` then? What is the point of `GameTask` being a template? Just store `std::function<void()>` and call it inside `execute`. You can convert any method call, with any parameters to `std::function<void()>` via lambda (you do that anyway in the commented section). Let the compiler store everything for you.

Comment: @freakish: To me the problem appears to be a mix of patterns. Both inheritance and templates are techniques that can be used to share common code, but for different use cases. Inheritance allows run-time substitution, while templates create instantiations at compile time. The combination breaks down here because `ITask` can't change the return type of `ITask::execute` at runtime.

Comment: @MSalters here's the rule of thumb: avoid templates whenever you can. The complexity they bring to the code is often not worth it. The rule of thumb number 2: avoid templates when you use virtual methods. You gain even less in such case. The rule of thumb number 3: templates are good for strong typing (e.g. `std::vector<T>` is good because we know underlying type `T`, not because of static polymorphism). But in your case you do the opposite: you erase type (function's signature) with `void execute()`.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/progschj/ThreadPool

Comment: @NicolBolas I updated the Q, so I think now it can be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working version of the code with some changes. Although the design could be improved a lot, BUT, I just changed your code to compile and work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <queue>

template<typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
class ITask
{
public:
   virtual ~ITask() = default;
   virtual void execute(Args ...) = 0;
};

template<typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
class GameTask : public ITask<ReturnType, Args...>
{
public:
   GameTask(std::function<ReturnType(Args...)>& func) :
      func_(func)
   {
   }

   void execute(Args ... args) override
   {
      func_(args...); 
   }

private:
   std::function<ReturnType(Args...)> func_;
};


// lets imitate some bigger classes with various methods
class BigClassA
{
public:
   void func1(int a) { std::cout << ++a; }
   int func2(const std::string& s) { std::cout << s; return b; }

   int b = 4;
};

class BigClassB
{
public:
   double func1(BigClassA& bca, int i) { bca.b += i; return 0.1; }
};

int main()
{
   BigClassA a;
   BigClassB b;

   // perform immediately by current main thread:
   a.func1(2);
   b.func1(a, 3);
   a.func2("Hello");


   //store under queue for later execution
   std::queue<std::unique_ptr<ITask<void , int>>> queue;

   a.func1(2);
    queue.push(std::make_unique<GameTask<void, int>>(std::function<void(int)>([&a](int x) { a.func1(2); })));

   b.func1(a, 3);
   queue.push(std::make_unique<GameTask<void, int>>(std::function<void(int)>([&b , &a](int x) { b.func1(a , 122); })));

   a.func2("Hello");  
   queue.push(std::make_unique<GameTask<void, int>>(std::function<void(int)>([&a](int x) { a.func2("Hi"); })));


   while (queue.size())
   {
      queue.front()->execute(3);
      queue.pop();
   }
}
```

**Edit 1:** Updated the `std::queue` member to work with polymorphic type.

Comment: I'd love to hear about the improvements if you can